# Store fixed data in Django: dictionary or sqlite?

Tags: python, django

I'm working in a project that retrieves some data from a rest service. One of the retrieved fields is a department number that need to be searched in a set of data in order to get the department name. That set of data has been given to me in a csv file (at least is not excel) with 1200 records.

The dataset is fixed and will not be updated (let's assume that's true) and the project doesn't have a database.
So I'm looking for the best alternative for storing this set: could be a hard coded dictionary or sqlite, what do you think? is there a better alternative?

Comment: _the project doesn't have a database._ Is SQLite a possibility then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a REST service, storing the data in sqlite is better because loading 1200 records from a hard-coded python dict creates overhead in both memory and loading time every time your REST service is called. sqlite is fully indexed on the filesystem so all data retrieval will be on an as-needed basis, which will create only a minimal overhead to each of your REST service call.